# Were professors Samuel S. Wilks and Daniel S. Wilks related?

Tags: history

Both are / were statistics professors.  Were they related?

Comment: (We have a tag for questions about the history of statistics. I don't see why this should be considered off topic here.)

Comment: If you mean the Daniel S. Wilks at Cornell, why don't you write him and ask?

Answer (score 6):

I am Daniel Wilks.  No relation to Samuel S, but I get this question a lot.

Comment: For those who might be wondering: user141794 indeed is using an e-mail account publicly associated with Daniel Wilks at Cornell University.  Welcome to our site, Dr. Wilks!

Answer (score 2):

I cannot currently say that they were not related, but we can at least say that Daniel is not Samuel's son. [This](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Biographies/Wilks.html) biography of Samuel S Wilks says [1]:

> On 1 September 1931 Wilks married Hattie Eugenia Orr (1906-2000), known as Gena. They had one child, a son named Stanley Neal Wilks born in 1932.

However, the elder Wilks would be of the right age to perhaps be a grandfather or great uncle to the younger one (or even some other, more distant relation, of course -- ultimately we're all related)

[1] J J O'Connor and E F Robertson (2014)
*Samuel Stanley Wilks*,
Biographies
MacTutor History of Mathematics archive
School of Mathematics and Statistics
University of St Andrews, Scotland
http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Biographies/Wilks.html